# Importing game source code into eclipse adt

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git

How to import a git clone into eclipse adt ?  I want to try and modify the asqare game ( https://code.google.com/p/asqare/source/checkout) to create a new game for nexus-5 device. I have a clone of the git on my disk, but I can't import/open the project in eclipse for editing it... Please help with the correct procedure for importing this project into eclipse adt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way. In eclipse:

- File -> Import
- Git -> Projects from Git, click Next
- select Clone URI, Next
- Location URI: https://code.google.com/p/asqare/ , Next
- master, Next
- Destination Directory: C:... (browse to a place you want), Next
- Import existing projects, Next
- Finish

This will clone the project in the place you specified and will import the project in the Eclipse Package Explorer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works nicely. I tried to follow this procedure to import another game, 2048-android-offline (https://github.com/uberspot/2048-android) but eclipse reports missing git-upload-pack on this URI. I have a local cloned copy of this project. Is there any other way to open this 2048 game in eclipse adt?

Comment: Yes, there is. Just follow these steps.
File -> Import;
Git -> Projects from Git;
select Existing local repository;
click Add;
Directory: C:\...\2048-android (browse to the project);
tick C:\...\2048-android\.git;
Finish;
Next;
Import as general project;
Finish.

Comment: Thanks. I can import the 2048 project into eclipse adt, but the files are very different from a normal android project. The suggested method imports all the JavaScript files and other html and css files. I am looking for modifying the layout and the way these tiles merge, for which I was looking for the java class file... Please help regarding how to proceed for modifying the layout and logic, and how to build and run the app from eclipse adt?

Comment: Ok, I see. You want to import it as an Android project. So here are the steps assuming you have Android Development Tools for Eclipse installed. File -> Import...;
Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace, Next;
Root Directory: ...\2048-android (browse to the project), Finish.